# calculate weights by columns with uneven NA using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data `foo` below. Each row has a sample size `n` and three variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. I'd like to calculate the weighted mean of each variable using `n/sum(n)` as the weights but omitting the values of `n` where there are NA values in variable (e.g., `x1`). I can do this by hand as below but wonder how one might do this with a `summarise_at` or similar in one go.

Suggestions appreciated. I'm sure this is trivial but I can't figure it out.

```
foo <- data.frame(n = c(99,12,53,12,19,21),
                  x1 = c(5,2,6,NA,13,78),
                  x2 = c(15,NA,60,NA,3,7),
                  x3 = c(2,7,4,9,4,2))
# weighted mean for x1
foo %>% 
  select(n,x1) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(w = n/sum(n)) %>%
  summarise(wMean = sum(x1*w))
# and for x2
foo %>% 
  select(n,x2) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(w = n/sum(n)) %>%
  summarise(wMean = sum(x2*w))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a two step approach. First, re-express each column (except `n`) as "itself times n, divided by the total of n where the current column is non-NA." That's the weighted value of each value using the weights that apply to that column. Then we sum each column excluding NAs.

```
foo %>%
  mutate(across(-n, ~.x * n / sum(n[!is.na(.x)]))) %>%
  summarize(across(-n, ~sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))

        x1       x2       x3
1 13.34314 25.35938 3.333333
```

Or as one line:

```
foo %>%
  summarize(across(-n, ~sum(.x * n / sum(n[!is.na(.x)]), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Edit -- as @ritchie-sacramento suggested, a more elegant equivalent would be:

```
foo %>%
  summarize(across(-n, ~ weighted.mean(.x, n * !is.na(.x))))
```

Comment: A simpler alternative is to use `~ weighted.mean(.x, n * !is.na(.x))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a much less concise but more expressive/legible version, you can turn the code you already have into a simple function that solves the problem, and then apply it via summarise().

i.e.

```
wMean <- function(n_, x) {
  tibble(n_ , x) %>% 
    drop_na() %>%
    mutate(w = n_/sum(n_)) %>%
    summarise(wMean = sum(x*w)) %>% 
    pull(wMean)
}


foo %>% 
  summarise(x1_mean = wMean(n, x1),
            x2_mean = wMean(n, x2),
            x3_mean = wMean(n, x3))


   x1_mean  x2_mean  x3_mean
  13.34314 25.35938 3.333333
```

Comment: Or more concisely / automatically: `foo %>% summarise(across(-n, ~wMean(n, .x), .names = "{col}_mean"))`

Comment: Very clean. Thanks for the answer.